# Simple Count and Sort on Association Cakephp 3

Tags: sorting, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I have students table and results table. Student has many results. A result is associated with only one student. So please what I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
$this->Students
    ->find('all')
    ->contain('Results')
    ->order('by count of results each student has' => 'asc');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you have defined in the model, is it hasOne relation or hasMany. Can you provide the Students model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$query = $this->Students->find()
    $query->select(['total_result'=> $query->func()->count('Results.id')])
    ->autoFields(true)
    ->contain('Results')
    ->leftJoinWith('Results')
    ->group(['Students.id'])
    ->order(['total_result'=>'ASC']);

debug($query->all());
```

More check [Here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-leftjoinwith)

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks a bunch

Comment: It should be noted that this will only work with DMBS that do allow including non-aggregated fields in the `SELECT` clause that do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. For other DBMS, or those that support it but are configured to not allow it (ex [**MySQL `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)), other solutions like for example subqueries in the `JOIN` clause have to be used. Maybe you can add a note and an example of that too?